# Nonequivalent norms on infinite-dimensional linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've just proven that for every infinite-dimensional space with a norm $(V, ||~||)$ we can find a discontinuous linear functional $ \phi $. But next I'm trying to prove the following:

The norm $ ||~|| $ is not equivalent to the norm $ |||~||| = ||~|| + |\phi| $ (meaning that identity from $ (V,||~||) $ to $ (V,|||~|||) $ is not a homeomorphism.

I can't find what might be wrong: differentiality or continuity? I was thinking that identity can't be differentiable in the point of discontinuity of $ \phi $, but I can't seem to show it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these two norms would be equivalent, there would exist a constant $c>0$ such that
$$
|||x||| = \|x\|  + |\phi(x)|\le c\|x\|\quad \forall x\in V.
$$
This would imply boundedness of $\phi$ a contradiction. So continuity goes wrong.

Comment: Well, I didn't think it would be that easy. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could also give me a hint on how to prove that at least one of these norms is not complete

Comment: @Jytug Use the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @azarel so you're saying that if they were both Banach spaces, then identity from $ (V, |||~|||) $ to $ (V, ||~||) $ would be open, but it clearly is not (since identity the other way around is not continuous). Is that right?

Comment: @Jytug Exactly, and the identity is continuous in one direction.